# Firewall Security Guidelines

Tags: security, firewall, best-practices

I'm looking for some best practices or Security guidelines for Firewall and VPN.
Trying to study a little more about network security and write a sort of decalogue (set of rules). Usefull to follow when implementing a new system.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

- Start with a two-way deny-all, then only add allow rules when a)
  requested, b) documented, c) reviewed by someone else and d) review
  their validity every quarter/6-months/year/whatever.
- Syslog and retain every deny for at least a quarter.
- Try to only allow through standard ports.
- Ensure all FW actions are authorised and audited.
- Dependant on volume maybe use Splunk to analyse where your denies are coming from, can be useful but can get expensive.
- Document everything to within an inch of its life, there's nothing as horrifying to new sysadmins as an undocumented FW.

Comment: +1 to starting with deny all. There're few things harder to debug than a firewall with accept all as the base rule

Comment: Thanks for your infos!! Have you any links or documents? like Cisco man or SANS docs?

Comment: I don't know about that last point...well, not the point itself, but rather the assertion.